# Use many text boxes but only one button

Tags: asp.net

So I have a web page where a user needs to be able to search by one or more parameter and click only one button and it finds whatever field is entered. We can start out with two fields and two buttons I already put on the page. I'm using a table to keep the spacing a little more clean, but I'm certainly not dedicated to it. Also, the page uses a master page. I have a feeling it is a feature in ASP.Net that is already done, I just have no idea which it is. Here is my code below:

Markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Search by last name: <asp:TextBox ID="searchTB" runat="server"/></td>
        <td style="padding-left: 10px;">Search by Organization: <asp:TextBox ID="SearchByOrgTB" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Search" /></td>
        <td style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;"><asp:Button ID="SearchbyOrgBtn" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="SearchByOrg" /></td>
    </tr>
</table><br />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TextBox LastName = (TextBox)this.FindControl("searchTB");
    Response.Redirect("OrgsByName.aspx?LASTNAME=" + searchTB.Text);
}
protected void SearchByOrg(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TextBox LastName = (TextBox)this.FindControl("searchTB");
    Response.Redirect("NamesByOrg.aspx?SectionName=" + SearchByOrgTB.Text);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an aspx page for every possible search pattern? What if the users enters a Lastname and a Sectionname?

Comment: I don't yet, but I do have the two mentioned in my code.

Comment: Do you want to keep only one click event handler?

Comment: What do you mean? I can call more than one method with a click?

Comment: technically? Of course, you can call one method, which in turn can invoke any number of methods.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that it can all be done in the code behind with if statements...

Comment: I was hoping there was an ASP function or something like that to make it easier, lol.